# Fixing Date Format in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

I am creating a dashboard in PowerBI, and I have problems formatting the date from "mm-dd-yyyy" to "mm/dd/yyyy" or whatever PowerBI will recognise as a date and not return error as input.

I have to load the data from several .txt files, so I am connecting a folder and combine them. Some of them have the following date format "mm.dd.yyyy" and most of them the following "mm-dd-yyyy". The first one, I can successfully convert to  "mm/dd/yyyy" in edit query. But the latter results to an error. Then, I tried to create another column with the following syntax: Date = format(column[Date], "mm/dd/yyyy"), which is just returning the date separated with dots again, so I cannot actually convert the data type to Date.

Obviously, I need to have the data type to "Date" in order to be accurate and also to be able to use slicer filters.

Comment: Make sure each file have a consistent format

Comment: Hi @PratikBhavsar, thank you for your response. I cannot edit the files I use as inputs. They are a result of a software and I should make an automated dashboard based on that. Which practically means that even if I fix their format, the future files will be inconsistent anyways.

Comment: @ioannisphilippides I have replicated your date formats and had success by using the 'Modelling' tab and changing the data category to date and then defauly summarisation to dd/mm/yyyy, have you tried this?